# Theres a better way of do this kind of query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Theres a better way of do this kind of query? (It's pseudocode) I don't know if the syntax it's ok but this is the idea:

```
SELECT S.*, isFromFriend = true
FROM messages AS S
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM friends)

UNION ALL

SELECT S.*, isFromFriend = false
FROM messages AS S
WHERE S.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM friends)
```

I need something like this on response, if my user is "userid=17" and I'm friend of user 25 but not friend of user 33:

```
{ "message": "hello", "userid": "25", "isFromFriend" = "true" }
{ "message": "hi!!!!", "userid": "33", "isFromFriend" = "false" }
```

My problem is with the **SELECT isFromFriend** field, I don't want to duplicate the query two times only changing the NOT IN and IN on WHERE because the real query is too big.

Comment: Thats hard to understand what you are after, it would be better if you provide some sample data and expected result out of those sample data.

Comment: You are right, I have edited the first post.

Comment: But to no advantage. Instead, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I edited my question other time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pseudocode is pretty unreadable and inconvenient. Better place your SQL code.
As for me, I would actually do something like this.

```
SELECT S.*, F.id AS Fid
FROM messages AS S
LEFT JOIN Friends AS F
ON s.id = F.UserId
```

So, you will get rows with Fid = null if there is no 'friend' or Fid = friend's id or user's id (it's up to your DB structure and query) if there is.
Anyway, I think that there is no difference in these queries' performance (at least, I can't call and explain it) - it's just my own opinion and habit. Your query is as compact and plain.

Comment: (F.id IS NOT NULL) AS isFromFriend will make it output true/false as original query had

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a little to Yeldar's answer. You could do:

```
SELECT S.*, CASE WHEN F.id IS NULL THEN false ELSE true END AS isFriend
FROM messages AS S
LEFT JOIN Friends AS F
ON s.id = F.UserId
```

This would give you the boolean field output